# How to get the device specific style resources?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, theming, tint

I have a Samsung specific bug, which I would like to fix. My problem is that some views are wrongly tinted and the design looks broken.

Now I want to see what Samsung messed up and I want to read the device specific styles. Which apk contains the related styles on a device, which I can reverse engineer to find out what is going on that device?

What I tried so far: I looked into the device and pulled out some apks, but I found nothing helpful yet. I also tried to ask my issue on the official Samsung Developer portal, however as I expected that was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specific layout for samsung like this:

```
if(Build.MODEL.contains("samsung")){
   setContentView(R.layout.samsung);
} else{
   setContentView(R.layout.anti_samsung);
}
```

Comment: Right, that would be a workaround, however at the current stage I still fail to get it working on that device. My question was where do I find the Samsung specific resource files?